# How to unit test with Jasmine when FormGroup is set to disabled?

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine

I havea a angular 8 application  and I am using Jasmine Karma for unit testing. And I want to test a Formbuilder that is disabled in the NgOninit function:

I have it like this: component.ts

```
constructor(
    private dossierService: DossierService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private dossierFileService: DossierFileService,
    private errorProcessor: ErrorProcessor,
    private dialog: MatDialog
  ) {
    this.dossierItems = this.route.snapshot.data.dossierItems;
    this.editDossierForm = this.formBuilder.group({});
    this.editDossierForm.disable();
 
    this.dossier = this.route.snapshot.data.dossier;
    this.dossierItems = route.snapshot.data.dossierItems;
    this.profileImagefile = this.route.snapshot.data.profileImage;
 
    this.editDossierForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: this.formBuilder.control(this.dossier.firstName, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(255)]),
      lastName: this.formBuilder.control(this.dossier.lastName, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(255)]),
      mobile: this.formBuilder.control(this.dossier.mobile, [Validators.maxLength(255)]),
      company: this.formBuilder.control(this.dossier.company, [Validators.maxLength(255)]),
      buddy: this.formBuilder.control(this.dossier.buddy, [Validators.maxLength(255)]),
      supervisor: this.formBuilder.control(this.dossier.supervisor, [Validators.maxLength(255)]),
      dateOfBirth: this.formBuilder.control(this.dossier.dateOfBirth)
    });
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editDossierForm.disable();
  }
}
```

and this is the spec file of it:

```
describe('DossierPersonalDataComponent', () => {
  let component: DossierPersonalDataComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DossierPersonalDataComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {


    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, DossierModule, BrowserModule],
      declarations: [DossierPersonalDataComponent],
      providers: [
          DossierFileService,
          ErrorProcessor,
          {
            provide: ActivatedRoute,
            useValue: {
              snapshot: {
                data: {
                  dossier: {
                    firstName: 'hello',
                    lastName: 'world',
                    mobile: '111-111-1111',
                    company: 'carapax',
                    buddy: 'bud',
                    supervisor: 'super',
                    dateOfBirth: '1900-01-01',
                  },
                  dossierItems: [], // mock
                  profileImage: '',
                }
              }
            }
          },
        {
          // DossierFileService, These have to be outside of the braces
          // ErrorProcessor,

          provide: DomSanitizer,
          useValue: {
            sanitize: () => 'safeString',
            bypassSecurityTrustHtml: () => 'safeString'
          }
        }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents()
      .then(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DossierPersonalDataComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
      });
  }));


  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

but in the instanbul coverage rapport this stays red:

```
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editDossierForm.disable();
  }
```

So how to coverage this part?

Thank you

oke,

if I do it like this:

```
  it('should create', () => {    
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

I get this error:

```
DossierPersonalDataComponent > should create
TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

and in my tesspec, I see this:

```
 get profileImageUrl() {
    return this.profileImagefile === null
      ? '/assets/placeholder.jpg'
      : this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(this.profileImagefile));
  }
```

and this line:

```
 ? '/assets/placeholder.jpg'
```

is in yellow. Branch not covered.

Comment: What I have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute a `fixture.detectChanges()`. Calling this the first time, it will trigger `ngOnInit`. After that it will just trigger change detection.

So depending on your tests, you can either include a `fixture.detectChanges()` inside the `beforeEach` block.

I would only recommend this approach if you don't want to spy or setup different mocks for things happening inside `ngOnInit` for each test case.

I usually add this inside every test case after I declared my spys. So your test would look something along those lines:

```
it('should create', () => {
    // spy on anything you would like. e.g the disable call of your form
   
    // then trigger onInit
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // then run your expectations
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Comment: if I do it like this:  it('should create', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  }); I get this error: DossierPersonalDataComponent > should create
TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

Comment: It looks like something is missing inside your TestBed setup. Could you please create a stackblitz and recreate your issue? It's hard to help otherwise.